# Could not restart apache

Tags: apache-2.2

I am trying to install phpUnit to work together with the zend framework. I followed this tutorial step by step [Click here for tutorial](http://grover.open2space.com/node/243)

In step 9 it is required to restart apache. And when i restarted i got the following error:

```
 /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
 * Restarting web server apache2                                                [Thu Dec 31 10:39:42 2009] [warn] The Alias directive in /etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf at line 3 will probably never match because it overlaps an earlier Alias.
[Thu Dec 31 10:39:42 2009] [warn] The Alias directive in /etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf at line 3 will probably never match because it overlaps an earlier Alias.
(13)Permission denied: make_sock: could not bind to address [::]:80
(13)Permission denied: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:80
no listening sockets available, shutting down
Unable to open logs
                                                                     [fail]
```

I am not sure how to solve this problem. Can anyone help me along?

Comment: Have you tried restarting it at least 3 times? - http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=W8_Kfjo3VjU (Sorry, couldn't help myself!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try running it as root, or doing `sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart`.

Answer (score 1):

http://wiki.apache.org/httpd/CouldNotBindToAddress

Furthermore, the start-up error suggests that you have overlapping definitions for an Alias, which you should fix.